# VB ComboBox not accepting 'Enter'

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a combo box that I want to accept enter from the edit area as selecting. I don't know if this is the best way, but based on other questions answered here I added a ComboBox_KeyPress routine to map 'Enter' to 'Tab'.

```
Private Sub MyCB_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles MyCB.KeyPress
       Dim tb As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
       If Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) Then
          If e.KeyChar.Equals(Chr(Keys.Return)) Then
             Me.SelectNextControl(tb, True, True, False, True)
             e.Handled = True
          End If
       End If
End Sub
```

If I select the drop-down portion of the combo box, type in my text and hit Enter, it works.  However, if I select the text edit portion of the box, type in my text and hit Enter, MyCB_KeyPress never gets called.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Code works for me.

Comment: That leads me to believe there is some property I need to set (or not set).  I've been trying various properties that seem related, but to this point nothing has changed this behavior.

Comment: Try recreating the problem in a new project.

Comment: The Enter key services an entirely different purpose in a GUI, it invokes the default "accept" action for a window.  Enshrined in the Form.AcceptButton property.  The Escape key is similarly special, triggers the Form.CancelButton.  And yes, setting AcceptButton makes it behave this way.  Making a GUI work like a console mode app is not a great idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Alex M. for getting me much closer! What I discovered is that neither KeyPress or KeyDown get called in this case. The KeyPreview property had no effect on that behavior. What **does** get called is KeyUp.  So this worked:

```
Private Sub MyCB_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyCB.KeyUp
   Dim cb As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
   If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
      Me.SelectNextControl(cb, True, True, False, True)
      e.Handled = True
   End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The event `KeyDown` is a lot easier to use when you're trying to capture (and read keys) as `e.KeyCode` is a `Keys` itself.

Additionally, consider setting `KeyPreview` on your ComboBox's container (your form) to `True` in your Form properties.

Thinking about my first point, you can do this:

```
Private Sub MyCB_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyCB.KeyDown
    Dim tb As ComboBox = CType(sender, ComboBox)
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        Me.SelectNextControl(tb, True, True, False, True)
        e.Handled = True
        'e.SuppressKeyPress = True - To remove that "beeping" when enter is hit.
    End If
End Sub
```